# Pass parameter to the "create" action of my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My view has a form_for that when submitted gets directed to the "create" action of my controller. How do I pass an additional param (apart from the form contents which is passed implicitly)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably get some use out of [hidden_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this? What if I want to send multiple params?